# When minimized lxpanel's 2nd level selection is unselectable

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, lxpanel

On Lubuntu 18.04-1 using LXDE default setup initially.

Displaying the panel on left works fine for selecting a VPN Connection under Connections lxpanel.

When I set minimize in Advanced tab, subsequent attempts to select the 2nd level item from an lxpanel fails with the panel tree/vector collapsing as the cursor transitions to the selectable item which is in this case a VPN Connection entry.

Specific dialog is using the nework manager to activate a VPN connection from the list of such connections, i.e.:
Select connections icon
Select VPN Connections -> list appears
Attempt to select item from list -> poof, entire lxpanel vector collapses.

This sequence works fine if *minimize panel when not in use* on the Advanced tab is not checked.

This raises a philosophical question for me about statefulness of desktop implementations. Should implementations of connected dialog entities (panels in this case) only respond to cursor movement/transition or should the user be able to alternatively set a flag / environmental var to demand sustained presentation of the subsequent panel/list (upon selection of the antecedent) until an entry is selected or an escape action is initiated.

I poked around LXDE and lxpanel stuff for a couple hours and found no flags that could allow the user to configure a change to the mouse transition trigger behavior.

I'd love pointers to discussions of this type of design trade-off,

but more importantly I'd like to change the lxpanel-to-lxpanel transition which is failing in the above instance. I need the screen realestate that the minimize provides.

Comment: +1 thanks for this, I'm about to ask this question but it seems it was a bug indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the Lubuntu Release Manager about this issue (I'm well connected, I know, but I help the Lubuntu team with some of their infrastructure so...), and they indicated this is a known bug already.

However, there is also known that LXDE's team more or less doesn't provide good fixes in a timely manner for LXDE bugs, and that has driven them to move to LXQt for 18.10 and further.

There isn't currently a fix currently stated by their teams at the moment for this issue, nor is there a known workaround.  However, it is **confirmed** that **this is a currently unfixed bug**.

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt response on both issues. Now I need to evaluate the difference in "weight" between the Gtk vs Qt libraries and related changes in applications. Care to comment on that as well?

Comment: @LeSnelson not with any experience, no.  It's a little heavier than LXDE from what I've heard, but a bit prettier and a bit nicer, though I've not used either enough to give you anything other than what i've heard as 'vague rumor' and just unsubstantiated claims from users